# How to parse a line with inconsistent order of values?

Tags: parsing

I have a bunch of automobile_information lines in a text file with attributes: year make model color.

However the attributes could be in any order, or they may or may not be present.

What would the best way to parse these attr's into individual columns?

Also, is there any theory on the subject of parsing inconsistent lines?

Comment: You should show sample input and expected output for this input. Extensive test suite would be required, because there is no algorithm to 'get exactly what I have in mind from non-regular data'.

Comment: What if I have a Peugeot 2008 manufactured in 2009? Or a green Mercury Topaz? You might have some ambiguities to deal with...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the range of valid values for different attributes don't overlap, then the value itself tells you which attribute it refers to.  For example "Toyota" can only be a make, not a year, model, or color.  If this is true for all possible attribute values, then you don't need to depend on the order of the field.

There are two general approaches to parsing:  syntax-driven or input-driven.  If your data had a consistent form, then you might choose a syntax-driven approach.  But since you don't have that, you have to use an input-driven approach.  Basically, you sit in a loop, reading the next "token" from the input, figure out what kind of token it is, and then set the appropriate attribute for the "current" car.  When you get to a record separator, you output the "current" car and then reset the current car to defaults.

Something like this:

```
CarInfo current_car;
current_car.Reset();  // sets the fields to default empty values
while (token = GetNextToken()) {
  if (token is a record separator) {
     Output(current_car);
     current_car.Reset();
  } else if (token is a make) {
     current_car.SetMake(token);
  } else if (token is a year) {
     current_car.SetYear(token);
  } ...
}
```

If there is some overlap in your values, e.g., "2000" might be a year or it might be a model for some hypothetical car, then you'll have to add a heuristic that takes an educated guess to figure out the type.  Perhaps you'll check and see if the year field has already been set or if the manufacturer has been set and you know that particular manufacturer has a model called 2000.  Hopefully you don't have to write too many rules like this.